# Sublime Text: How to hide all code and show only comments

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Lets say we have code like this:

```
//description 1
code block 1 {
..
..
}

//description 2

code block 2 {
..
..
}
```

In sublime text, how to show only the comments and hide all the code?

Answer (score 8):

In a code like the one you've used as example, you can just "Fold All" the code.

Set the cursor outside any function then:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

then you'll see only the comments and the function/struct signiatures (hidding the body).

Comment: What if the above code block is enclosed within script tag and present in a html page? I suppose fold all won't work in this way right? It will fold the entire tag itself.