# Sublime Text: Hide all code and show only comments

Tags: css, editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I find it tedious to manage very large style sheets in Sublime Text 3.

Some of my stylesheets are about 2000 lines of code. I am trying to figure out how to navigate more easily within the stylesheet. I already know about bookmarks and the brilliant search function, but another way would be to hide/fold all code and show comments only. Tis way it would be easier to find the correct place you want to go to.

So is there a way to hide all code below a comment? This would be something as the opposite of [Fold Comments](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Fold%20Comments)

I know [Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697884/hugo-corr%C3%A1) proposed the classic "fold all" solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265047/sublime-text-how-to-hide-all-code-and-show-only-comments). But I would like to hide absolutely all code and display comments only.

For example:

```
/*******************************************************************
Description 1
*******************************************************************/

Hide/fold all code between here...
...
...
..
.
.

/*******************************************************************
Description 2
*******************************************************************/
```

Comment: You can fold all non-comment by opening the console ``ctrl+` `` and writing `view.fold(view.find_by_selector("-comment"))`

Comment: Thanks. That works. Would be nice to have a shortcut though.. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can fold everything, which is not a comment by opening the console `` ctrl+` `` and write `view.fold(view.find_by_selector("-comment"))`.
This searches all regions with the selector `- comment`, which means everything except comments. Afterwards these regions are folded.

If you want to create a keybinding for it, just create a plugin. Open `Tools >>> Developer >>> New Plugin` and paste:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class FoldEverythingExceptCommentsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        regions = self.view.find_by_selector("-comment")
        self.view.fold(regions)
```

Afterwards add this to your `Key Bindings - User` to add a keybinding for the command:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+f"],
    "command": "fold_everything_except_comments"
},
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `arrows` in the far left of the text editor. Sublime has the line number listed down the left and beside those numbers are tiny arrows.

Comment: I have voted the answer down because I already said in the question that I want to hide all code. Using just the arrows will still display functions in the code.