# Sublime Text: Hide all code and show only comments (with line break)

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Previously I asked a question on how to [hide everything except comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282130/sublime-text-hide-all-code-and-show-only-comments) in Sublime Text 3.

[r-stein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5963435/r-stein) worked out a handy plugin that was able to do this:

```
import sublime_plugin

class FoldEverythingExceptCommentsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        regions = self.view.find_by_selector("-comment")
        self.view.fold(regions)
```

Here are some example pictures:

[image]

This is how the code will look initially...
If we use the plugin to hide everything except the comments, we get this:

[image]
As you can see everything falls on one line. This can be confusing and messy.
What I really want to do now is to get something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to edit the plugin to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you posting this as a seperate question instead of commenting on the answer that provided this functionality in the first place?

Comment: [you did comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282130/sublime-text-hide-all-code-and-show-only-comments#comment62097910_37286397) "Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!" but asking this question would suggest that it was **not** exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: At the time when I made the question I was satisfied with the answer, but that was one month ago so I assumed I had to start a new question.

Comment: I'd still recommend commenting on that answer explaining that you are looking for a tweak and add a link to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the previous plugin to keep leading "newlines" and "newlines and the indent" after the fold region:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


def char_at(view, point):
    return view.substr(sublime.Region(point, point + 1))


def is_space(view, point):
    return char_at(view, point).isspace()


def is_newline(view, point):
    return char_at(view, point) == "\n"


class FoldEverythingExceptCommentsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        regions = view.find_by_selector("-comment")
        fold_regions = []

        for region in regions:
            a, b = region.begin(), region.end()
            # keep new line before the fold
            if is_newline(view, a):
                a += 1
            # keep the indent before next comment
            while is_space(view, b - 1):
                b -= 1
                if is_newline(view, b):
                    break
            # if it is still a valid fold, add it to the list
            if a < b:
                fold_regions.append(sublime.Region(a, b))

        view.fold(fold_regions)
```